# Making request without refreshing page with blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

Please i am new to blazor, I am building a pet project and i want to make a call to the server to do so validation if the text entered into an input textbox is equals 10. I know in a normal MVC project we will be using AJAX to make this request, But i can't wrap my head around what will be used in blazor. Thanks

Comment: server side blazor, or client side?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: *i want to make a call to the server* - if this is SSB, that's essentially an incorrect mindset. Try and think of SSB as an application that runs *on the server* and the browser is just some kind of remote desktop view of the server side app. It's arranged such that by the time the user has typed 10 into the box (and not even tabbed out of it, if you want) Blazor has already sent the data to the server; it isn't something you have to do - data is sent to the server in the same way that you pressing keys into a VNC window on your pc, open to a server sends the input to the server

Comment: Client side blazor @Lei Yang

Comment: You're studying this framework wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add Country class:

> ```
> public class Country
> {
>     public string? Name { get; set; }
>     public bool Saving { get; set; }
> }
> ```

2. Add CsValidation Class:

> ```
> using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
> using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms;
>
> namespace BlazorApp3
> {
>     public class CsValidation : ComponentBase
>     {
>         private ValidationMessageStore? messageStore;
>
>         [CascadingParameter]
>         public EditContext? CurrentEditContext { get; set; }
>
>         protected override void OnInitialized()
>         {
>             if (CurrentEditContext == null)
>             {
>                 throw new InvalidOperationException(
>                     $"{nameof(CsValidation)} requires a cascading " +
>                     $"parameter of type {nameof(EditContext)}. " +
>                     $"For example, you can use {nameof(CsValidation)} " +
>                     $"inside an {nameof(EditForm)}.");
>             }
>
>             messageStore = new(CurrentEditContext);
>
>             CurrentEditContext.OnValidationRequested += (s, e) =>
>                 messageStore.Clear();
>             CurrentEditContext.OnFieldChanged += (s, e) =>
>                 messageStore.Clear(e.FieldIdentifier);
>         }
>
>         public void DisplayErrors(Dictionary<string, List<string>> errors)
>         {
>             if (CurrentEditContext != null)
>             {
>                 foreach (var err in errors)
>                 {
>                     if (messageStore != null)
>                         messageStore.Add(CurrentEditContext.Field(err.Key), err.Value);
>                 }
>
>                 CurrentEditContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
>             }
>         }
>
>         public void ClearErrors()
>         {
>             if (messageStore != null && CurrentEditContext != null)
>             {
>                 messageStore.Clear();
>                 CurrentEditContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

3. Add razor page to test add new country validation:

> ```
> @page "/CreateCountry"
>
> <EditForm Model="@NewCountry" OnValidSubmit="OnSave">
>     <CsValidation @ref="CsValidation" />
>     <DataAnnotationsValidator />
>
>     <div class="form-group mb-3">
>         <label class="form-label">Country Name</label>
>         <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="@NewCountry?.Name" />
>         <ValidationMessage For="@(() => NewCountry?.Name )" class="small" />
>     </div>
>
>     <hr />
>
>     <div class="d-grid gap-2">
>         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-danger">Save</button>
>     </div>
> </EditForm>
>
> @code {
>     public Country? NewCountry { get; set; }
>     private CsValidation? CsValidation { get; set; }
>
>     public async Task OnSave()
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             CsValidation.ClearErrors();
>
>             var errors = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
>
>             //Test if country added befor
>             if (CountryService.IsNameAdded(NewCountry?.Name))
>                 //Add validation error
>                 errors.Add(nameof(NewCountry.Name), new() { "This country has been added." });
>
>             if (errors.Any())
>                 //Show validation errors
>                 CsValidation.DisplayErrors(errors);
>             else
>             {
>                 //Save new country
>             }
>         }
>         catch (Exception ex) { //Handel execption }
>     }
> }
> ```

You can update last razor file to get data from api service:

> ```
> @page "/CreateCountry"
>
> @inject HttpClient http
>
> <EditForm Model="@NewCountry" OnValidSubmit="OnSave">
>     <CsValidation @ref="CsValidation" />
>     <DataAnnotationsValidator />
>
>     <div class="form-group mb-3">
>         <label class="form-label">Country Name</label>
>         <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="@NewCountry?.Name" />
>         <ValidationMessage For="@(() => NewCountry?.Name )" class="small" />
>     </div>
>
>     <hr />
>
>     <div class="d-grid gap-2">
>         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-danger">Save</button>
>     </div>
> </EditForm>
>
> @code {
>     Country? NewCountry { get; set; }
>     private CsValidation? CsValidation { get; set; }
>
>     public async Task OnSave()
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             CsValidation.ClearErrors();
>
>             var errors = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
>
>             //Call api service and get data
>             var response = await http.GetFromJsonAsync<bool>($"/api/iscountryadded?name={NewCountry?.Name}");
>             //Test if country added befor
>             if (response)
>                 //Add validation error
>                 errors.Add(nameof(NewCountry.Name), new() { "This country has been added." });
>
>             if (errors.Any())
>                 //Show validation errors
>                 CsValidation.DisplayErrors(errors);
>             else
>             {
>                 //Save new country
>             }
>         }
>         catch (Exception ex)
>         { //Handel execption }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```